# How to explain/isolates changes in a population?

Tags: classification, clustering, generalized-linear-model, cart

For my study I have a dataset in which I have observations of individuals and the amount of money they earn every year.
I also have the year of observation, and a lot of variables, categorical and numerical, such as the age, working class, type of car, ownership etc.

On a global level I can see that the average is increasing : in average they earned more in 2016 than in 2015, and more in 2017 than in 2016.

All the year the population change a bit : people get older, change jobs, or just quit the survey and other enter.

**The question is** : how can we explain this increasing ?

- My first intuition : Build a GLM with the variables. Well, if I do it without using "year" as a variable, the estimation is decreasing across the year. If I had it, I have a coefficient of 1 for year1, 1.07 for year2 and 1.06 for year3.
- I built a tree on year 2015 to create distinct clusters based on the money they earn. Then I applied this tree for the other year and I saw that cluster with low expected earnings have a bigger population across the year, and those with high expected earnings a smaller. I noticed that this could explain the results for the GLM part. But I also noticed that for every cluster, the actual earning is higher than the expected.

So my two methods seem to indicate that the increasing is due to a global increasing.

**But** I wonder if there is actually a small population of my survey for which the earning gets bigger every year and could explain this phenomena.
This population could be described with my variables and would have an atypic evolution across the years.

Is there a good way to find this ? Does my method seems to be a good way to deal with such a problem ?

Thanks